# AngularJs - binding passed in paramter to object from different controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, ionic-framework

I'm having difficulties in solving this. What I'm trying to achieve is to update iterated objects which is passed in to a function in a different controller.

Here is my controllers -

```
angular.module('eatmapp.controllers', ['eatmapp.services'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.intoCart = function(item) {
      if(item.type == 'variations'){
        item = newItemObj;
      }
   }
})
.controller('BrowseCtrl', function($scope, dataService, $localstorage) {
    dataService.getItems().then(function(returnData) {
        $scope.items = returnData.products;
    })
});
```

Here is my view -

```
<div ng-controller="BrowseCtrl">
    <div class="list card product" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="intoCart(item)">
      <div class="item item-text-wrap">
          <span class="ifs-productcat" ng-repeat="category in item.categories">{{category}}<span ng-if="$index != item.categories.length - 1">,</span></span><br>
          <h3>{{item.title}}</h3>
          <h3>Rs.{{item.price}}</h3>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to update item object with newItemObject in iteration(ng-repeat) implemeted in template view after doing some condition check with method (intoCart) in another controller(AppCtrl). I'm fairly new to javascript programming and I'm looking for some help.

Comment: Make that function a part of some service, then you can inject that service in any controller and use that function

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Ionic has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Sorry I removed ionic. This work was in ionic but yea it has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I had was not able to get access to 'ng-repeat' child scope in controller. 
I solved this using 'this.item' in controller rather than passing the whole object or index.

HTML -

```
<div class="list card product" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="intoCart()"></div>
```

Controller -

```
angular.module('eatmapp.controllers', ['eatmapp.services'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.intoCart = function() {
      item = this.item; // current (ng-click) child scope of ng-repeat 
      if(item.type == 'variations'){
        item = newItemObj;
      }
   }
})
```

Now, whenever I made changes to 'item' object, it automatically updates scope in view (ng-repeat).

Comment: I was going to suggest querying the parent object but sounds like you've got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Once way I like to handle this is by using services as setters and getters.  The problem is you have to include the service with every controller that needs to access it, but if you don't have too many it's no big deal.  So something like this:

```
.service('userFirstName', function() {
      var userFirstNameProp;
      return {
        getter: function() {
          return userFirstNameProp;
        },
        setter: function(value) {
          userFirstNameProp = value;
        }
      };
    })
```

Then you can call userFirstName.getter() or userFirstName.setter("John") as appropriate.

Comment: I tried that. I even tried using a function within same controller. Correct me if I'm wrong, doesn't angular watch changes in each iterations? I want to update each item in ng-repeat if certain condition are met.

Comment: Oh...you want it to update/re-run ng-repeat if something changes in another controller?  Just to be clear, you're updating the value in the controller scope and ng-repeat doesn't seem to be running again?

Comment: Yes. I could not get access to child scope of ng-repeat in controllee even if I pass the whole item object as parameter. Anyway I solved using 'this.item' in controller.